# Exponential fit in Origin doesn't converge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

[image]

I am using a data treatment program called Origin, wich I think many of you are familiar with. The data I have is time vs voltage in the resistor of an RL circuit. 
 The expression that describes the behaviour of the voltage in the resistor when this goes from the maximum voltage $V_0$ to zero is given by
**$V=V_0e^{\frac {-t}{T}}$**, where $T$ is the characteristic time of the circuit.

When I try to fit my data with this expression, I get the image you see above. The fit doesn't converge and Origin doesn't iterate. I'd like to know whether the problem is in the data or in the program itself.

Thank you very much for reading and sorry if my English is poor or confusing.

Comment: I added the image just now, I had forgot it.

Comment: What did you use as starting values for the parameters? How close is the result with those starting values?

Comment: https://imgur.com/onNoHYV that's how I set the parameters. I didn't put anything in parameter intialization, but I used that function to fit the increasing in the voltage of the resistor and with a RC circuit, and it worked pretty well in those cases.

Comment: There are a few things to try.  Your program may not like  using values that are very close to zero.  Try using data that runs from  0 to 0.075 ms and see if that data set converges.  Also, try using less data points.  Since you only have two parameters in the final equation (e.g., $V_0$ and $T$), you can easily select 10 points throughout the range of interest and see if you can converge on the smaller data set.  Good luck.

Comment: Looks like you gave two initial values for V and none for T. You should be able to get pretty close estimates for both from inspection of your data.

Comment: If you use $\log(V)$ as the dependent variable (in the vertical axis), you can use linear regression instead that will give you the parameters directly.

Comment: The problem is in the custom fit you've made, you've got x as a parameter, but it's not set up so Origin can vary x. You could try using Origin's built in exponential decay fit.